# Lucene 5.0 UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, lucene, nlp

I use Lucene 5.0 and I want to add my own stopwords.

```
    CharArraySet stopSet = StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET;
    stopSet.add("i");
    stopSet.add("m");
    stopSet.add("t");
    stopSet.add("can");
    stopSet.add("said");
    tokenStream = new StopFilter(tokenStream, stopSet);
```

And this found in [how to add custom stop words using lucene in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008999/how-to-add-custom-stop-words-using-lucene-in-java). But it does not work in my work. The problem is as follows.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArrayMap$UnmodifiableCharArrayMap.put(CharArrayMap.java:606)
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet.add(CharArraySet.java:115)
at Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

How could I solve it. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

StandardAnalyzer's stop set is an unmodifiable set.  So you can't modify it.  Easy enough to deal with though, just copy it:

```
CharArraySet stopSet = CharArraySet.Copy(StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET);
stopSet.add("i");
//etc.
```

You can then pass that stopset into the [`StandardAnalyzer` constructor](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html#StandardAnalyzer(org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet)), or create your own `StopFilter` with it.

The answer you are referring to is just incorrect on that front.  It was unmodifiable in Lucene 3.6 as well (and at least as early as 2.9).

Wait... I wrote that answer.  *Embarrassing*

Comment: Thanks. Another thing is, I need to read a large json file. Could you recommend a way to do this.

Comment: That is the correct solution to the problem. Thank you. @PatrickWAN please accept this answer if it solved your problem